# Is it possible to include an Xhtml2pdf object in a Reportlab pdf?

Tags: reportlab, html2pdf, xhtml2pdf

I have a combination of plain text and HTML that I want to combine into 1 pdf file. The plain text I can easily write to a pdf using reportlab. Adding the HTML turns out to be more difficult.

This HTML contains images and CSS from an external source.

My initial plan was to use xhtml2pdf to convert the pieces of html into a pdf and then merge that into the reportlab object. It would like something like below.

My question is, is this possible? If yes, could you point me towards any resources because I can't find any. If no, is there any other way to achieve this?

[image: Combination of reportlab canvas and xhtml2pdf]